# MapView User's Current Location Regular Pin

Tags: swift, annotations, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

Im having trouble putting a "regular" pin on the user's current location. I searched around but couldn't find much. Right now, in the user's current location I just have the location beacon. How can I change it to just the regular "pin"? I tried nnotationView?.annotation = annotation  but this did not seem to work.

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "AnnotationView")

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotationView")
        }

        if let title = annotation.title, title == "Park Test" {

            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Park icon test")

        } 

   else if annotation === mapView.userLocation {

            return nil
        }

        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true

        return annotationView

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code using annotations.

```
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?  {

    let identifier = "MyCustomAnnotation"

    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.isEnabled = true
        annotationView?.isDraggable = true
        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

Call the delegate by adding this code.

```
 var point = MKPointAnnotation()
 self.point.coordinate = location.coordinate
 self.point.title = ("Your title")
 self.point.subtitle = (" your subs")
 self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.point)
 //selects the annotation
 self.mapView.selectAnnotation(self.point, animated: true)
```